# How to send an image directly from flask server to html?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am new to flask and am trying to make an app such an image is taken by the html and js from the webcam and then it is sent to the server with ajax request. I got this part. Then some processing is done on the image and it has to be sent back to the frontend. I know how to send data normally in flask, as in

```
@app.route('/')
def function():
    return render_template("index.html", data = data)
```

But in python images are in form of numpy arrays and js cannot read numpy arrays and convert it to images( atleast I don't know of any way to do that). so what is the way this can be done?

Comment: flask has function send_file() and maybe it can works with data from pillow - because you have to send data compressed in format png or jpg, not raw data from numpy. Or maybe it can run with `io.BytesIO` which can create file object in memory

Comment: @furas I don't want to save the processed image though.

Comment: browser can't display numpy data. It needs PNG/JPG. You can use PIL/pillow to convert numpy array to object `PIL.Image` which has function to save it as JPNG/PNG in file. But instead of real file on disk you can use file created in memory using `io.ByteIO`.

Comment: @furas if I save the image in memory with `io.BytesIO`, how do I access the image in HTML? what will be its path?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This shows how to convert `numpy` array to `PIL.Image` and then use it with `io.BytesIO` to create file PNG in memory.

And then you can use `send_file()` to send PNG to client.

```py
from flask import Flask, send_file
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import io

app = Flask(__name__)

raw_data = [
    [[255,255,255],[0,0,0],[255,255,255]],
    [[0,0,1],[255,255,255],[0,0,0]],
    [[255,255,255],[0,0,0],[255,255,255]],
]

@app.route('/image.png')
def image():
    # my numpy array 
    arr = np.array(raw_data)

    # convert numpy array to PIL Image
    img = Image.fromarray(arr.astype('uint8'))

    # create file-object in memory
    file_object = io.BytesIO()
    
    # write PNG in file-object
    img.save(file_object, 'PNG')
    
    # move to beginning of file so `send_file()` it will read from start    
    file_object.seek(0)
    
    return send_file(file_object, mimetype='image/PNG')


app.run()
```

The same way you can send it as GIF or JPG.

Comment: I got that but how do I display the image on front end?

Comment: if you put `<img src="/image.png">` in HTML - you can use JavaScript to insert it - then browser will  automatically download and display it.

Comment: eventually Ajax can receive data from `/image.png`, encode to `base64` and put all as string in `'<img src="data:image/png;base64,image_encoded_base64'" />

Comment: but how do I know the processing at backend has been completed, so I can insert the html? also which of the html should I insert, one in first comment or second?

Comment: I think you could do: ajax sends data to server and waits for answer, server processes data and uses `send_file()` to send image, ajax receives image and uses `base64` to put as string in `'<img src="data:image/png;base64,image_data_encoded_to_base64'" />`

Comment: but how do I get the base64 in the js? I am new to flask, so don't know the details.

Comment: if you can, please give me an eg html code for how this works

Comment: I would encode it in Python and send already base64 to client

Comment: using Google I found that JavaScript has built-in function `btoa(str)` which create base64.

Comment: no, my question is how do I receive the base64 at the client? should I render the html again and pass it as data?

Comment: when you use ajax to send data then it receives data from server. So server may use `send_file()` to send string base64. And it insert `<img>` to HTML in browser. I don't remeber but with jQuery it could be `$(where_to_insert).insert("<img src=...>")`

Comment: I think you did not get my question. How do you receive the data? like, my ajax request is :`$.ajax({ type:"POST", url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/apply_filter',
                    data: { /*data*/ }}).done(function(){ console.log("sent");});` so how do I get the base64?

Comment: you have response from server as `data` in `.done(function(data){...})`

Comment: one last thing, will the `data` variable have the `bas64` of the image? and also can the variable directly used or is it an array or dictionary?

Comment: I tried your way, but I am getting an error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL` in html

Comment: here is my done `function .done(function(data){
                    var image = document.createElement("img")
                    image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + data;
                    document.body.appendChild(image);
                });`